# Is every non-intersecting closed loop about the origin with winding number 1 ambient $\mathbb{R}^{2}$-isotopic to the unknot?

Tags: homotopy-theory, knot-theory

Let $\gamma(t): [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ be a counterclockwise-oriented closed loop that *does not intersect itself* and *does not intersect the origin*: $\gamma(0)=\gamma(1)$. Further, assume that the winding number of this curve about the origin is 1. Does there exist an ambient isotopy of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ that takes $\gamma(t)$ to $(\cos t, \sin t)$? I believe a homeomorphism from $\gamma(t)$ to $(\cos t, \sin t)$ can be constructed by sending an arbitrary nonzero point $(x, y)$ to the the point $\frac{1}{|\gamma(T_{xy})|}(x, y)$ where $\gamma(T_{xy})$ is the point where $\gamma(t)$ intersects the ray from $(0, 0)$ to $(x, y)$. Call this homeomorphism $H_{1}$. This assumes that that $\gamma(t)$ only intersects the ray from $(0, 0)$ to $(x, y)$ at exactly *one point*. In this case, an ambient isotopy of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ taking the identity to $H_{1}$ (and hence $\gamma(t)$ to $(\cos t, \sin t)$ ) can be constructed as follows $H_{t}(x, y) = \frac{(1-t)|\gamma(T_{xy})| + t}{|\gamma(T_{xy})}(x , y)$. Each $H_{t}$ should be a homeomorphism because the factor $\frac{(1-t)|\gamma(T_{xy})|+t}{|\gamma(T_{xy}|}$ is never zero when $t$ is between $0$ and $1$. This also presumes that each homeomorphism sends $(0,0)$ to $(0,0)$.

However, an arbitrary non-intersecting closed curve $\gamma(t): [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ (even one that has winding number 1), may intersect a ray from $(0,0)$ to a nonzero $(x, y)$ *more than once*. How can the above ambient isotopy of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ be extended to one that takes an arbitrary non-intersecting closed loop, $\gamma(t)$, of winding number 1, to $(\cos t, \sin t)$. Is it possible to first construct a homeomorphism, $H_{\frac{1}{2}}$ of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ that takes $\gamma(t)$ to another closed loop that only intersects the ray from $(0,0)$ to $(x, y)$ at exactly one point. This homeomorphism could then be extended to an isotopy from the identity to $H_{\frac{1}{2}}$. The above argument would be then be used to construct an isotopy from $H_{\frac{1}{2}}$ to $H_{1}$. However, I am unsure how to fill in the details of constructing the homeomorphism $H_{\frac{1}{2}}$ or the isotopy between it and the identity. Any assistance here would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the [Jordan-Schönflies Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoenflies_problem)? In the level of generality that you are stating this problem, that's what your going to need.

Comment: I have heard of theorems like this (Jordan Curve Theorem). From the Wikipedia article, I understand that a homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ exists that takes the image of the simple closed curve to the standard circle. However, I do not see a prior how this can be extended to an isotopy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a proof using the Schönflies Theorem together with the Classification of Surfaces.

The first step is to apply the Schönflies Theorem, which gives you a homeomorphism of the plane $h : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ such that $\gamma' = h \circ \gamma$ is a counterclockwise parameterization of the unit circle. Your original counterclockwise parameterization of the unit circle, let me call it $\delta$, has been taken to another simple closed curve $\delta' = h \circ \delta$.

The second step is to radially isotope $\gamma'$ to a circle that I'll denote $\gamma''$, and which is so large that $\delta'$ lies on the inside of $\gamma''$.

The third step is to consider the closure of the region lying on the inside of $\gamma''$ and the outside of $\delta'$; let's call this $A$. It follows that $A$ is a compact surface with boundary, the only issue here being to check that each component of the boundary has a collar neighborhood. This is obvious for the circle $\gamma''$, using an inner coller neighborhood. And then the outer collar neighborhood of $\delta$ provides a collar neighborhood of $\delta'$ in $A$.

The fourth step is to apply the classification of surfaces to $A$, to conclude that $A$ is homeomorphic to the annulus $S^1 \times [0,1]$ (I can supply more details here as needed), with $S^1 \times \{0\}$ corresponding to $\gamma''$ and $S^1 \times \{1\}$ correpsonding to $\delta'$.

The fifth step is to use that homeomorphism to isotope $\gamma''$ to $\delta'$.

The final step is to pull back the isotopy (going first from $\gamma'$ to $\gamma''$, and then from $\gamma''$ to $\delta'$) via the hoeomorphism $f$ to get the desired isotopy from $\gamma$ to $\delta$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Would you be able to provide more details about how the homeomorphism from $A$ to $S^{1} \times [0, 1]$ provides an ambient $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ isotopy from $\gamma”$ to $\delta’$?

Comment: In brief, $S^1 \times \{0\}$ is isotopic to $S^1 \times \{1\}$ in $S^1 \times [0,1]$. Now pull that isotopy back to $A \subset \mathbb R^2$ via the homeomorphism $A \mapsto S^1 \times [0,1]$, to get an isotopy in $A$ from $\gamma''$ to $\delta'$.

Comment: I'm being a bit fuzzy about the parameterizations of $\gamma''$ and $\delta'$; there is one last detail that any two orientation preserving self-homeomorphisms of $S^1$ are isotopic to each other.

Comment: Yes, I figured a pullback of the isotopy would be how you get an istotopy from $\gamma”$ to to $\delta’$

Comment: Also, what are the necessary and sufficient conditions for the closure of a region outside of a simple closed curve $C_{1}$ and inside another simple closed curve $C_{2}$ (assuming $C_{1} \cap C_{2} = \emptyset$) be homeomorphic to $S^{1} \times [0, 1]$? Is the criteria about the collar neighborhood of $C_{2}$ and $C_{1}$ necessary? If so, what would be an example of curves where this region would not be homeomorphic to $S^{1} \times [0, 1]$? What would it be homeomorphic to in this case?

Comment: My answer essentially contains a proof that under the hypotheses of your last comment, and -- to be completely explicit -- assuming also that one of $C_1$ or $C_2$ is inside the other one, the (inclusive) region between $C_1$ and $C_2$ is *always* homeomorphic to $S^1 \times [0,1]$.